# How to insert in different tables with one form asp core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to asp core and I want to insert values from a form into two tables with a condition,

these are my tables :

```
 public class Brand
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NomBrand { get; set; }
}



public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Type? Type { get; set; }
    public string NomBrand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Unite? Unite { get; set; }
    public string Prix { get; set; }

    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

}
```

I want it that if a user insert a product type with "brand" value so it insert it into brand table and if the type is "Product" then insert it into product table

Comment: There's no form here, no tables, no condition, no values, no product types. We have no idea what kind of data store you're using, nor what's stopping you from selecting or inserting anything.

Comment: amir, what have you tried so far? (Update your answer, don't reply in the comments.)

Comment: Someone answered and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a dropdownlist in form to pass model type.And in action put both Brand type parameter and Product type parameter.Here is a demo:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestBind(Brand b,Product p,string ModelType)
        {
            if (ModelType == "Brand")
            {
                //save Brand b to  brand table
            }
            else {
                //save Product p to product table
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View:

ModelType
        
            Brand
            Product

```
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">BrandID</label>
    <input name="BrandID" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">NomBrand</label>
    <input name="NomBrand" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">ID</label>
    <input name="ID" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nom</label>
    <input name="Nom" class="form-control" />
</div>



<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

result:

[image]